# make div span the width of the page

Tags: html, css, header, width

I am trying to make the header to span the width of the page. Below is the css code I have already. There is some text written in the div but it gets cut off in the middle.

```
header {
    background-color:#02350B;
    margin-top:auto;
    display:table-row;
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Why `display:table-row;`? Also, some more context would be useful

Comment: please add html. are you using any frameworks such as bootstrap?

Comment: Add the html and maybe add a jsfiddle if yoo=u know how to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

just change `display: table-row;`  to `display: block;`

Becouse `display: block;` is 100% width as default :)

Good luck! :)

Comment: no that didn't work. it actually removed the div completely

Comment: ohh actually it did. forgot to add the semi-colon at the end. cheers for your help :D

Comment: no problem, display block is 100% width as default :)